# Wechat The appid has no permission to get the phone number

Tags: wechat, wechat-miniprogram

WeChat mini program account has been verified and authenticated. I tried to retrieve phone number. can you please help me to solve issue, it prompted failed to get the phone number
Error: The appid has no permission
Any suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your company account information. It has no permission If your Company is not in china.
For more information:
https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/dev/framework/open-ability/getPhoneNumber.html